# How do I remove all tags from a docker image?

Tags: amazon-ecs

We have a docker image that is untagged.
I created a tag on this image, but now I want to remove that tag and have the image completely untagged again.

According to this [boto3-batch-delete-image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.batch_delete_image) and [aws-cli-batch-delete-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/batch-delete-image.html)

You can remove a tag, but if you remove the LAST tag, the image will be removed.  I don't want that.
I just want to untag an image without deleting the image.

In other words, I want to remove the tag and have the image untagged.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, as of now, you could only [remove the tag from the repository](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/untag-resource.html) but not from an image, so this is a limitation from AWS

```
--resource-arn (string)

The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the resource from which to remove tags. Currently, the only supported resource is an Amazon ECR repository.
```

May be in future we could expect improvements in this API

Comment: I think that link is for AWS Tags, not Docker tags.  I'm trying to remove docker tags, not AWS Tags. (I may be wrong though)

Comment: one way you can achieve that is by pushing another image with the same tag as the image that needs to be untagged.